# Amazon Kinesis getRecord() mismatch results

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I just started using Kinesis whose API is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html)

I've used this to push **100 records** to **kinesis**

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
        putRecordRequest.setStreamName(myStreamName);
        putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes()));   
        putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey(String.format("partitionKey-%d", j));   
        PutRecordResult putRecordResult = kinesisClient.putRecord(putRecordRequest);
        System.out.println("Successfully putrecord, partition key : " + putRecordRequest.getPartitionKey()
                + ", ShardID : " + putRecordResult.getShardId() + ", Sequence No : "+ putRecordResult.getSequenceNumber());
}
```

Now I want to get the number of records which got pushed. For that I am using this :

```
Iterator<Shard> shardIterator = getTotalShardsIterator();//Implemented and giving perfectly all the shards.....
```

Now using the above iterator I am getting the count as:

```
.....
while (shardIterator.hasNext()) {
        Shard shard = shardIterator.next();
        String shardId = shard.getShardId();
        int datacount = getDataCount(shardId, myStreamName);
        totalStreamDataCount+= datacount;
        System.out.println("Data Count for Shard " + shardId + " is : " + datacount); 
}
.....
```

Here is my function **getDataCount(shardId, myStreamName)**

```
 public static int getDataCount(String shardId, String streamName) {
        int dataCount = 0;
        String shardIterator;
      GetShardIteratorRequest getShardIteratorRequest = new GetShardIteratorRequest();
      getShardIteratorRequest.setStreamName(streamName);
      getShardIteratorRequest.setShardId(shardId);
      getShardIteratorRequest.setShardIteratorType(ShardIteratorType.TRIM_HORIZON);


      GetShardIteratorResult getShardIteratorResult = kinesisClient.getShardIterator(getShardIteratorRequest);
      shardIterator = getShardIteratorResult.getShardIterator();
      GetRecordsRequest getRecordsRequest = new GetRecordsRequest();
      getRecordsRequest.setShardIterator(shardIterator);
      getRecordsRequest.setLimit(1000);

      GetRecordsResult getRecordsResult = kinesisClient.getRecords(getRecordsRequest);
      List<Record> records = getRecordsResult.getRecords();
      if(!records.isEmpty() && records.size() > 0){
          dataCount = records.size();
          Iterator<Record> iterator = records.iterator();
          while(iterator.hasNext()) {
              Record record = iterator.next();
              byte[] bytes = record.getData().array();
              String recordData = new String(bytes);
              System.out.println("Shard Id. :"+shardId+"Seq. No. is : "+"  Record data :"+recordData);
          }
      }


    return dataCount;
}
```

But this code is giving mismatch results every time I run this, like sometimes it shows 81 some time 91

Please shed some light on this..:)

Comment: Can you try to infinitely loop your shards to get records until get 100 records. Each GetRecords request might not give you all the records that you have put in that shard.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `List<Record> records = getRecordsResult.getRecords();` with `List<com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.Record> records = getRecordsResult.getRecords();` in order to avoid type ambiguity?

Comment: According to http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/kinesis/latest/kinesis-dg.pdf , there is a 3 seconds latency between insertion into stream and availability for read of a record, could it be that the last records were just not available yet? Have you wait between insertion and read?

Comment: I know it's like 2 years later now... it would be very useful to look into using the [Kinesis Client Library](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-kcl.html) - basically a small library that makes consuming records from Kinesis much easier/simpler

Answer (score 0):

Records pushed to kinesis has limit (data/sec) so records may get failed if it exceeds this (Speed depends on number of shards used ).
Now you can get the failed records count with kinesis API and Push those again to kinesis.

```
List<CompletionStage<PutRecordsResponse>> putRecordResponseCompletionStage = <PutRecordRequest call with Stream Name , Partition key and Data>;

AtomicInteger failedCount = new AtomicInteger();
      AtomicInteger recordsCount = new AtomicInteger();

     int loopCount = 0;
      for (CompletionStage<PutRecordsResponse> stage : putRecordResponseCompletionStage) {
        loopCount++;
        try {

          PutRecordsResponse response = stage.toCompletableFuture().get();
          failedCount.addAndGet(response.failedRecordCount());
          recordsCount.addAndGet(response.records().size());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }


Check example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-sdk.html)
```